# JavaFX: RadioButton doesn't change userData on first click

Tags: java, javafx, radio-button, javafx-8

On every scene I have multiple toggleGroups with two RadioButtons each. No matter which RadioButton on which Scene I select first, the listener won't catch that. Instead of saving the setted user data it's still null. If I press it a second time, it works.

When I change the scene it's the same all over again. The listener doesn't listen to the first action.

Is this a known bug? I save the userData like this:

```
@FXML private RadioButton rbCheck11; @FXML private RadioButton rbCheck12;
@FXML private ToggleGroup group1;
public static String[] values = new String[326];

@FXML
private void testing() {
rbCheck11.setUserData(1); rbCheck12.setUserData(0);
group1.selectedToggleProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (group1.getSelectedToggle() != null){
            values[0] = group1.getSelectedToggle().getUserData().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FXML file you connect a callback with `testing()`:

```
@FXML
private void testing() { ... attach selectedToggleProperty of the ToggleGroup ... }
```

You did not share the FXML, so it's just a guess, that for example you set `onAction` of the `RadioButton`s to `testing`:

```
<RadioButton fx:id="rbCheck11" layoutX="121.0" layoutY="115.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
   onAction="#testing" text="RadioButton">
   <toggleGroup>
      <ToggleGroup fx:id="group1" />
   </toggleGroup>
</RadioButton>
<RadioButton fx:id="rbCheck12" layoutX="127.0" layoutY="166.0" mnemonicParsing="false" 
   onAction="#testing" text="RadioButton" toggleGroup="$group1" />
```

In this case `testing` will be executed only, if you clicked on one of the `RadioButton`s.

And as long as `testing` attaches the listener on the `selectedProperty` of the `ToggleGroup`, the listener will be executed only on the selection change.

Even worse, every press on the radio button will attach a new listener, so you will have more and more listener on the group.

To solve this, move the body of `testing` to the `initialize` method of the controller, to attach it to the group only once, as soon as the FXML file is loaded. Then remove `testing` from the controller completely.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Wish I would've asked earlier - would've spared me a lot of time setting all the RadioButtons onAction.